# How to prove computational cost of taking matrix powers

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

How would I go about **proving** the computational bound of an operation where I'm repeatedly taking a dot product between an $n\times n$ square matrix and its self for up to $n$ times? 
(Is this even the correct place for me to ask this question?)

Comment: Are you using the usual dot product?

Comment: That's about $\log n$ matrix multiplications ...

Comment: What does the "dot product" of matrices refer to?

Comment: By "dot product," I'm referring to the "usual" dot product. i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: I think the problem is too vague. Missing attempts. It's hardly to figure out where actually your point is. Are you stuck with a single operation, or the iteration, or trying to get a better bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [computational complexity of matrix multiplication is between $O(n^{2.37})$ and $O(n^3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra), depending on naivety the algorithm you use. Let's use $O(n^k)$.

So if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and you compute $A^m$ by naive matrix multiplication, it will cost $O(n^km)$.

If you want to be a little smarter and compute the power by diagonalization, the complexity of finding the eigendecomposition is generally considered around $O(n^3)$, although it technically has no finite bound on the number of operations of course (e.g. see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62904/complexity-of-eigenvalue-decomposition) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix)). Then you can take the matrix power by just taking $n$ numbers to the $m$th power (at *worst* $O(nm)$ and can be better (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring))) and doing $2$ matrix multiplications (negligible).
So the cost will be more like $O(n^3 +nm)$, which can be much cheaper even in this naive setup.

---

Edit: here's some details on why naive matrix multiplication has that many operations.

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$. Then $C=AB\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$.

Standard matrix multiplication for one element is given by:
$$
C_{ij} = \sum_{p=1}^m A_{ip} B_{pj}
$$
How many operations is this (for one element)? It is $m$ additions and $m$ multiplications, i.e. $2m$ floating point operations. But there at $nk$ elements to fill. Thus, naive "dot product" multiplication requires $2nkm$ operations.
If $n=k=m$, this is $O(n^3)$.

Now, if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and you want to compute $A^w=A\ldots A$ naively, it will take $w$ matrix multiplications, each costing $O(n^3)$. Hence, the cost is $O(n^3w)$.

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't completely answer my question.

Comment: @devinbost what else are you interested in?

Comment: How do I prove that those operations actually have that computational cost?

Comment: @devinbost I edited the post; is that helpful?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!